# string builder appendline tab but equal spacing

Tags: tabs, stringbuilder

I am using mail merge and displays Name, Phone and fax column through stringbuilder append line with tab. It is working well. But the prob is when the length of Name is diff from other rows, it has diff spacing.

it looks like the upper pic but I need it to look like the lower pic :

[click this for pic](http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6204/6072928058_b58c16966d.jpg)

Is there a way I can make them equal no matter what the length of each row's name is? I know one solution is to separate the phone and fax and declare them as another column but is there a way without doing that? any formatting I need to do?
thanks.

```
foreach (var item in _list)
            {
                List.Append(item.FullNameDF + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "\n");
                List.Append(item.Add1 + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "\n");
                List.Append((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.HomePhone) ? String.Format("{0:(000)000-000}", Convert.ToInt64(item.HomePhone)) : string.Empty) + "\t" + "\t" + "\t" + "\n");

                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use tables in situations like this.

```
List.Append("<table>");
foreach (var item in _list)
{
    string phone = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.HomePhone) ? String.Format("{0:(000)000-000}", Convert.ToInt64(item.HomePhone)) : string.Empty;
    List.Append(String.Format("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>{1}</td><td>{2}</td></tr>",item.FullNameDF, item.Add1 ,phone);
}
List.Append("</table>");
```

Comment: hi thank u for response but this is not working when stringbuilder is returned as string :(. this is the error I get-> Record 1 contained too few field delimiters ( , ). this is the text that appears in my txt file as datasource of mail merge. [pic text](http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6203/6075520004_55205309e7.jpg).The delimiter there is comma(,). SO I am not sure why it says contained too few field delimiters. thanks